# Use formula or Flow to set a value on an object?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am new to Salesforce and I am unsure when I should use a formula, versus when I should use a Flow.

We just started using a new external HR system that assigns values to each of our employees, and we need to track these numbers in our system, so on the User object we created a field called:

```
ExternalHrEmployeeNumber
```

On our Opportunities, I also created a field called:

```
ExternalHrEmployeeNumber
```

I think maybe I can create a formula that looks like this:

```
 $User.ExternalHrEmployeeNumber__c
```

And set the "Function" to be "TEXT" so that this is copied over as a text value?

Would the value copy over automatically?

Or I could create a Flow that triggers whenever an Opportunity is created?

One more question:

On the Opportunity, if I create a custom field, I see I can create a formula that allows me to set the value to $User.ExternalHrEmployeeNumber__c , but in this case does $User refer to whoever created the record, or to the current user, who might be modifying it?

Comment: Do you want to populate the field from User object?

Comment: Assuming you don't have too many unique relationship paths, and you have a relationship from the one object to another, cross-object formula fields can simplify your implementation. Read more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_cross_object.htm&type=5).

Comment: Yes, I want to copy the value from the User object to the Opportunity.

Comment: One more question, on the Opportunity, if I create a customer field, I see I can create a forumla that allows me to set the value to $User.ExternalHrEmployeeNumber__c , but in this case does $User refer to whoever created the record, or to the current user, who might be modifying it?

Comment: Do you want to show the current user's ExternalHrEmployeeNumber field?

Comment: I guess so? Mostly this is for integration with an external system, for which I'll use an Outbound Message. So I just need to copy over the $User.ExternalHrEmployeeNumber__c from User to Opportunity, so it is available when the Opportunity is edited, so that the value can be sent in the Outbound Message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the current user's ExternalHrEmployeeNumber  who is viewing the record you can use formula field and use `$User.ExternalHrEmployeeNumber__c`. Only issue is formula fields are not editable .

If you want Created user's ExternalHrEmployeeNumber you can use `CreatedBy.ExternalHrEmployeeNumber__c` in formula.

If you want that field to be editable in UI then you may have to use Flow to populate the value.